# Checking for empty fields without using fetch

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some problems with checking if the field is empty or not in SQL using PHP without using mysql_fetch_array().

I have this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei');
$remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
$date_added = date ("Y-m-d");
$time_added = date ("h:i:s a");
$lname = $_SESSION['user']['last_name'];
$fname = $_SESSION['user']['first_name'];
$minitial = $_SESSION['user']['middle_initial'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "thisdb");


if(empty(`TIME_IN_1`)) {
$query = "INSERT INTO time_logs (LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_INITIAL, DATE, TIME_IN_1, TIME_IN_1_REMARKS) VALUES('$lname', '      $fname', '$minitial', '$date_added', '$time_added', '$remarks')";
}

else {
$query =  "UPDATE time_logs SET TIME_IN_2 = '$time_added' where LAST_NAME = '$lname' AND DATE = '$date_added'";
}

$save = mysqli_query($con, $query);
header("Location: time_in_complete.php");
```

What I basically want to accomplish is if the TIME_IN_1 field is empty, the data will be added there. If it is not empty, then the data will be added to the TIME_IN_2.

Apprently, this line:

```
if(empty(`TIME_IN_1`))
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should fetch your database before... Else php doesn't know your datas

Comment: you want to check the values from db without fetching? no, you must fetch it first

Comment: On which part do I need to use fetch?

Comment: Where did you define `time_in_1`? If its in the database, you need to retrieve it first from the database, so you execute a query search first before you actually attempt to set this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$first_query = "SELECT TIME_IN_1 FROM time_logs WHERE LAST_NAME = '" . $lname . "' AND FIRST_NAME = '" . $fname . "'";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $first_query);
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($data);

if($num_row == 0) {
$query = "INSERT INTO time_logs (LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_INITIAL, DATE, TIME_IN_1, TIME_IN_1_REMARKS) VALUES('$lname', '      $fname', '$minitial', '$date_added', '$time_added', '$remarks')";
}

else {
$query =  "UPDATE time_logs SET TIME_IN_2 = '$time_added' where LAST_NAME = '$lname' AND DATE = '$date_added'";
}

$save = mysqli_query($con, $query);
header("Location: time_in_complete.php");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am getting a Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch(). :(

Comment: I really appreciate your help, good sir. But the Update query doesn't seem to work. It is just adding a new record in the time_logs table. :(

Comment: Please tell me the response of `var_dump($data);`

Comment: I am really sorry but I don't have any idea about var_dump() or how to tell its response. I still don't know much about PHP. @_@

Comment: I have updated my post, normally it will show you the content of $data, copy all the content and past in comment

Comment: array(1) { ["TIME_IN_1"]=> string(8) "04:52:32" } is it this one?

Comment: Yes, therefore this field is not empty... 
Normally it should update this record and don't insert new...

Comment: Thank you again for your help but it is still inserting a new record. :(

Comment: Are U using the last update ? `if($data['TIME_IN_1'] == '00:00:00') {` and no `if($data['TIME_IN_1'] != '00:00:00') {`

Comment: Yes, sir. But now it is not inserting any records.

Comment: Ok, if TIME_IN_1 = empty is that there is no record? 

Look the last update pls

Comment: the if($data['TIME_IN_1'] == '00:00:00') { doesn't insert any record at all, sir. The last update however is adding a new record. I'm really sorry about this and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please +1 the useful answer and close this post ;)

Comment: Done. :) I actually just added another '=' in if($num_row == 0) { and then it worked! Thank you so much for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Try a query like:

```
SELECT TIME_IN_1 from time_logs where LAST_NAME = '$lname' AND DATE = '$date_added'
```

Then:

```
// Default to true and set this false if we find a value
$bIsEmpty = true;

// Check if any rows match
if ($result->num_rows > 0){

  // Yes a row matches, so check if we have a value
  $row = $result->fetch_object();
  if ($row->TIME_IN_1 != "")
       $bIsEmpty = false;
}

if ($bIsEmpty === true){
    // Do your insert
} else {
    // Do your update
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @markt but I'm getting a little confused. The query above would not work because the condition LAST_NAME = '$lname' AND DATE = '$date_added' is not being satisfied because there are no values inserted in the database.

Comment: that is why you should check $result->num_rows. If this is 0 then your insert will be performed - or am I mis-understanding something here?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I really appreciate it but the code above doesn't update the inserted values, instead it is creating a new record.